# OAuth using JWT for Box API

Tags: http, go, oauth-2.0, jwt, box-api

I am attempting to make calls to the Box API in order to upload files remotely without any user interaction other than running a script. I am trying to implement this in Go, and I am using the method of JWT to avoid the need for any login authorization with normal 3-legged oAuth. I am able to generate a JWT but when I use this JWT to try to obtain an access token, my HTTP request is returning an empty body as a response with a 400 (Bad Request) error. I am not sure why it is a bad request as I think I have all the necessary information in my request. Is there anything important that I might have missed in constructing my HTTP request?

The following is my code used for generating the JWT and attempting to use that JWT to get an access token. Calling the CreateJWTAssertion function returns a working JWT, but calling SendOAuthRequest is not returning the intended access token.

```
// APPUSERNAME - used to name the user when creating an App User
const APPUSERNAME string = "box-reporter"

// JWTAUTHURL - URL for oAUTH for Box
const JWTAUTHURL string = "https://api.box.com/oauth2/token"

// JWTUSERURL - URL for creating an App User
const JWTUSERURL string = "https://api.box.com/2.0/users"

// JWTGRANTTYPE - mandatory parameter for box oAuth
const JWTGRANTTYPE string = "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer"

// oAuthResponse holds decoded JSON response from Box
type oAuthResponse struct {
    AccessToken  string   `json:"access_token"`
    Expires      int      `json:"expires_in"`
    RestrictedTo []string `json:"restricted_to"`
    TokenType    string   `json:"token_type"`
}

// AppUserRequest holds  JSON request to create an AppUser
type AppUserRequest struct {
    IsPlatformAccess bool   `json:"is_platform_access_only,bool"`
    Name             string `json:"name"`
}

// AppUser holds the newly created AppUser
type AppUserResponse struct {
    Usertype      string  `json:"type"`
    ID            string  `json:"id"`
    Name          string  `json:"name"`
    Login         string  `json:"login"`
    CreatedAt     string  `json:"created_at"`
    ModifiedAt    string  `json:"modified_at"`
    Language      string  `json:"language"`
    Timezone      string  `json:"timezone"`
    SpaceAmount   float32 `json:"space_amount"`
    SpaceUsed     float32 `json:"space_used"`
    MaxUploadSize float32 `json:"max_upload_size"`
    Status        string  `json:"status"`
    JobTitle      string  `json:"job_title"`
    Phone         string  `json:"phone"`
    Address       string  `json:"address"`
    AvatarURL     string  `json:"avatar_url"`
}

// Client - holds main client details
type Client struct {
    _PublicKeyID  string
    _ClientID     string
    _ClaimSub     string
    _ClientSecret string
}


// CreateJWTAssertion - build up the JSON Web Token for oAuth
func CreateJWTAssertion(PublicKeyID string, ClientID string, Sub string, user *AppUserResponse, keyPath string) (string, error) {

    var signingKey []byte
    var err error
    var msg, tokenString string

    signingKey, err = ioutil.ReadFile(keyPath)

    if err != nil {
        msg = "Unable to read signing key. Please ensure your private signing key is in the ./keys/ directory"
        return msg, err
    }

    // Generate JTI Value
    jti, err := exec.Command("uuidgen").Output()
    if err != nil {
        msg = "Unable to generate JTI value"
        return msg, err
    }   

    token := jwt.New(jwt.SigningMethodHS256)
    claims := make(jwt.MapClaims)
    token.Header["alg"] = "HS256"
    token.Header["typ"] = "JWT"
    token.Header["kid"] = PublicKeyID
    claims["iss"] = ClientID
    claims["aud"] = JWTAUTHURL
    claims["jti"] = jti
    claims["exp"] = time.Now().Add(time.Second * 45).Unix()

    // Create the JWT either for the enterprise or for a specific user.
    if user.ID != "" {
        claims["box_sub_type"] = "user"
        claims["sub"] = user.ID
    } else {
        claims["box_sub_type"] = "enterprise"
        claims["sub"] = Sub
    }
    token.Claims = claims

    // Sign the JWT
    tokenString, err = token.SignedString(signingKey)

    if err != nil {
        msg = "Unable to sign token, please check that you have a signing key in ./keys/"
        return msg, err
    }

    return tokenString, err
}

// SendOAuthRequest - Sends a POST to authenticate against Box using JWT Assertion
func SendOAuthRequest(ClientID string, ClientSecret string, JWToken string) (string, error) {

    var err error
    var msg string
    var decodedResponse *oAuthResponse

    hc := http.Client{}
    form := url.Values{}

    // Build form to POST
    form.Add("grant_type", JWTGRANTTYPE)
    form.Add("client_id", ClientID)
    form.Add("client_secret", ClientSecret)
    form.Add("assertion", JWToken)

    // Here is where the code stops working, returns an empty body
    // The request looks like it should be working
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", JWTAUTHURL, strings.NewReader(form.Encode()))

    //
    req.Close = true
    //

    req.PostForm = form
    req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    if err != nil {
        return msg, err
    }

    //
    fmt.Println(req)
    //

    resp, err := hc.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        msg = "Error submitting request to Box API"
        return msg, err
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    // Debugging the HTTP requests and responses here
    //fmt.Println(resp)
    fmt.Println(resp.Status)
    fmt.Println(resp.Body)
    //

    err = json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&decodedResponse)

    if err != nil {
        msg = "Error decoding OAuthResponse"
    } else {
        // We only need the Access Token
        msg = decodedResponse.AccessToken
    }

    return msg, err
}
```

The HTTP response and response body look as follows:

```
400 Bad Request
&{0xc4202be0c0 {0 0} false <nil> 0x5f48b0 0x5f4840}
```

My HTTP request is as follows:

```
&{POST https://api.box.com/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1 1 1 
map[Content-Type:[application/x-www-form-urlencoded]] 
{0xc4200f06c0} 0x5f3e90 1125 [] true api.box.com map[] 
map[client_id:[***Client ID Here***] client_secret:[***Client Secret Here***] 
assertion:[***JWT Here***] 
grant_type:[urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer]] 
<nil> map[]   <nil> <nil> <nil> <nil>}
```

Comment: First, I think you do not need to add Content-Type header ( maybe it should be `application/json`) . Second thing you losing `error response body` when decodeing, where validation information should be attached. In box documentation I see that as grant_type you should send just `authorization_code` https://developer.box.com/reference#token